# Using __overrides__ in device tree prevents driver from being loaded

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto, device-tree

Hello I've created a custom device tree overlay in order to support my own device. I've integrated it in yocto by adding a patch to the kernel.

I also wanted to allow changing device parameters by simply changing data in boot/config.txt so I added **overrides** section in the device tree overlay file. But the problem is that when this section is present my driver is not being loaded by the kernel. When I drop this section from a file, everything works fine. A driver is loaded and I can operate on it. What may be a problem here?

Not working device tree overlay:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

&soc {
hatch2sr {
    compatible = "hatch2sr";
    pwm-names = "motor1";
    pwms  = <&pwm 0 1000000>;
  
    openpossensor-gpios  = <&gpio 3  1>;
    closepossensor-gpios = <&gpio 26 1>;
    relay-gpios =          <&gpio 25 1>;
};
__overrides__ {
    openpos_sensor_pin    = <&hatch2sr>,"openpossensor-gpios:4";
    openpos_sensor_flags  = <&hatch2sr>,"openpossensor-gpios:8";

    closepos_sensor_pin   = <&hatch2sr>,"closepossensor-gpios:4";
    closepos_sensor_flags = <&hatch2sr>,"closepossensor-gpios:8";

    relay_pin             = <&hatch2sr>,"relay-gpios:4";
    relay_flags           = <&hatch2sr>,"relay-gpios:8";
};
};
```

Working device tree:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

&soc {
    hatch2sr {
        compatible = "hatch2sr";
        pwm-names = "motor1";
        pwms  = <&pwm 0 1000000>;
      
        openpossensor-gpios  = <&gpio 3  1>;
        closepossensor-gpios = <&gpio 26 1>;
        relay-gpios =          <&gpio 25 1>;
  };
};
```

Last line from /boot/config.txt:

> dtoverlay=hatch2sr

Kernel compiles and boots without any complaints.

Comment: It is probably because the `&hatch2sr` reference does not resolve to anything, so the loader failed to apply the overlay. Try labelling the node, e.g. `hatch2sr: hatch2sr {`.

Comment: I added an additional label, and it partially works. Partially, because driver has been loaded but adding dtoverlay=hatch2sr,openpos_sensor_pin=23,closepos_sensor_pin=24,relay_pin=25 to config.txt didn't change anything.

Comment: Perhaps the `__overrides__` node needs to be in the root node of the device tree rather than within the `&soc` node.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that `&hatch2sr` cannot be resolved because there is no label by that name. The Raspberry Pi loader will not apply the overlay if it cannot resolve the references. That can be fixed by appending a label to the intended node as shown below:

```
&soc {
    hatch2sr: hatch2sr {
```

The other problem is that the Raspberry Pi loader is not applying the device-tree parameters specified in the `__overrides__` node when loading the overlay. I think that is because the `__overrides__` node needs to be placed in the root node of the device tree, but it is currently in the `&soc` node. Moving the `__overrides__` node as shown below might fix the problem:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

&soc {
    hatch2sr: hatch2sr {
        compatible = "hatch2sr";
        pwm-names = "motor1";
        pwms  = <&pwm 0 1000000>;
  
        openpossensor-gpios  = <&gpio 3  1>;
        closepossensor-gpios = <&gpio 26 1>;
        relay-gpios =          <&gpio 25 1>;
    };
};

/ {
    __overrides__ {
        openpos_sensor_pin    = <&hatch2sr>,"openpossensor-gpios:4";
        openpos_sensor_flags  = <&hatch2sr>,"openpossensor-gpios:8";

        closepos_sensor_pin   = <&hatch2sr>,"closepossensor-gpios:4";
        closepos_sensor_flags = <&hatch2sr>,"closepossensor-gpios:8";

        relay_pin             = <&hatch2sr>,"relay-gpios:4";
        relay_flags           = <&hatch2sr>,"relay-gpios:8";
    };
};
```